# Can I request github to delete an existing fork of my private repo?

Tags: github

I made a repo just now and commit the first version. This repo should be made private. During the time when finishing payment and changing from public to private, someone has forked this repo.

I read the introduction of github, it says If I change a public repo to a private one, the existing forks will be kept in a separate network, it means it will still exists.

So I want to know, can I request github workers to delete this existing fork? I must keep this repo private, it has some confidential information. I think github worker should help to make it.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but any local clone of that fork can then be pushed again to a *new* non-forked repository. Created on GitHub or elsewhere.

So it really depends on *when* that fork was created: if it was after you started to put confidential information, said sensitive data are not safe (ie could be made public again) even if the fork were to be deleted.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Now I just want to quickly delete the fork, but cannot find any contact information of the developer. Github also provides a DMCA takedown service. @Vonc Do you know some quick methods to delete the fork?

Comment: @zhangjie You need to contact GitHub support and explain your case: they can tell you what is or is not possible. See https://github.com/contact.

Comment: The confidential information is associated with our organization's middleware code. Maybe it's not so important, but it should be removed.

Comment: @zhangjie At least make sure your own repo does not reflect anymore that information: https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/